# Последовательность не содержит элементов

Tags: c#

Код:

```
model.MLSide = new List<Models.LSide>();

foreach (var d in model.LSide)
{
    var x = modelg.Gate.Where(d1 => d1.Pass != null && d1.Pass.Notify=="true" && d1.Pass.Awbs.Awb == d.awb);
    //if (x.Count() > 0)
    //{
        //Ошибка
        x.First().Name = d.fgate;
        model.MLSide.Add(d);
    //}
    //else { }
}
```

При `x.First().Name = d.fgate;` ошибка:

> Последовательность не содержит элементов

Каждый из листов точно содержит данные, которые отвечают условию.

Comment: `x.First()` пытается получать первый элемент последовательности, если последовательность пустая- вызывает исключение. Можно сделать вывод что при заданном предикате у вас нет значений.

Comment: Какой тип у `model`?

Comment: Как проверялось, что _Каждый из листов **точно** содержит данные, которые отвечают условию_?

Comment: что значит "каждый из листов содержит данные, которые отвечают условию"? вы же одну и ту же коллекцию `modelg.Gate`  каждый раз фильтруете

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо `First()` и `Where()` используйте `FirstOrDefault()` с постпроверкой на нулл

```
model.MLSide = new List<Models.LSide>();

foreach(var d in model.LSide) {
  var x = modelg.Gate.FirstOrDefault(d1 => d1.Pass != null && d1.Pass.Notify == "true" && d1.Pass.Awbs.Awb == d.awb);
  if (x != null) {
    x.Name = d.fgate;
    model.MLSide.Add(d);
  }
}
```

**UPD:** код можно дальше модифицировать, чтобы исключить повторную фильтрацию:

```
model.MLSide = new List<Models.LSide>();
var source = modelg.Gate.Where(d1 => d1.Pass != null && d1.Pass.Notify == "true");
foreach(var d in model.LSide) {
  var x = source.FirstOrDefault(d1 => d1.Pass.Awbs.Awb == d.awb);
  if (x != null) {
    x.Name = d.fgate;
    model.MLSide.Add(d);
  }
}
```